# Why does my model become distorted when adding bones with Automatic Weights?

Tags: rigging, vertex-weights

After adding bones to the model, the whole model breaks down horribly.

Here are screenshots:

Before: https://ibb.co/Ycm9QVL
[image]

After adding bones to the model With Automatic Weights: https://ibb.co/2sXCVxx
[image]
Maybe someone knows why this happens?

Comment: The skeleton must be in rest pose when you attach the mesh to it. Select every bones in pose mode, hit ctrl+a and select apply rest pose, then try again the parenting.

Answer (score 0):

Blenders automatic weights are pretty meh. especially for a model of that complexity. youll probably be better off using manual weighting or envelope weighting

Comment: What is "meh."?

Comment: bad, terrible. not so great? what word do you want. you know that feeling of being underwhelmed with the shrug no sound. yea that

Answer (score 0):

The bones in your image don't seem to be fitted correctly with the character, the fingers for example aren't even close to matching up with the mesh and considering all the accessories this character has attached to their belt you will need to do some weight painting manually.

Blender can't magically know how these bones should influence your mesh you have to guide it the best you can and then refine the weight painting as you go. Automatic weighting can get you part of the way there and the better rig the better the weighting will be.